# Galaxy S tablet won't add app shortcuts to home screen

Tags: applications, tablet, home-screen-shortcuts

I have just bought my first tablet, Samsung Galaxy S. Two days after it stopped adding downloaded apps shortcuts to home screen. Apps still work, they are accessible through some digging inside tab, but it obviously is some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1):

You probably disabled it in a setting.

Go to Play Store -> Settings and click "Add icon to Home screen" under "General"

Answer (score 0):

In my case:  **in the LAUNCHER activity must not be**
category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).